# HTMX form not getting file upload succesfully with django

Tags: python, django, htmx

I have this form:

```
class FormCotacao(forms.Form):
    descricao = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Descrição',
        max_length = 200,
        required = True
    )
    valor1 = forms.FloatField(
        label = "Valor 1 (R$)",
        required = True
    )
    orcamento1 = forms.FileField(
        label = "Orçamento 1",
        widget = forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': '.pdf, .xls, .xlsx'}),
        required = True
    )
```

This htmx:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" hx-enconding="multipart/form-data" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ orcamento.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="addItemCotacao">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" hx-get="{% url 'visualizar-orcamento' id %}" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#itemsAdicionados">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="submit" hx-post="{% url 'item-cotacao' id %}" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#itemsAdicionados" class="btn btn-primary" name="addItemCotacao">Salvar item</button>
</form>
```

And this is the view to which it's directed:

```
def orcamentoCotacao(response, id):

    usuario = response.user
    orcamento = Orcamento.objects.get(id=id)

    if orcamento.aprovado != True:

        if response.method == 'POST':
            form = FormCotacao(response.POST)
            arquivos = response.FILES
            if form.is_valid():
                pass
        else:
            form = FormCotacao()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'id': id
            }
            return render(response, "main/partials/item-cotacao.html", context)
```

When the user uploads files in the form, they show up in response.POST but, for some reason, there's nothing in response.FILES. What might be the problem?

Comment: You have attr misspelling "hx-encoding"? Could that be the reason?

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you very much!